# Expression For Last Day of January in Current Year

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, expression, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I want to know what expression what I use to find specifically the last day of the month of January for the current year. Can anybody help me with this specific expression in SSRS? Trying to use for a parameter value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be as simple as something like this:

```
=CDate("1/31/" & DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Today))
```

You may need to change this a bit depending on the date format of where you live. This one above would be fine anywhere in the US.

```
=CDate("31/01/" & DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Today))
```

This one could be best for Europe.

```
=CDate(DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Today) & "-01-31")
```

Above works, too.

Play around with the idea. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the last day of the January is the 31st day of the Year. I am not sure if you are specifically asking for the date or the weekday name. So below are the expressions you can use.

> Date of the last day of January for current year: (01/31/2017)

```
=DateAdd("d",-DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear,Today,0,0)+31,Today)
```

> Weekday of the last day of January for current year: (3)

```
=Weekday(DateAdd("d",-DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear,Today,0,0)+31,Today))
```

> WeekdayName of the last day of January for current year: (Tuesday)

```
=WeekdayName(Weekday(DateAdd("d",-DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear,Today,0,0)+31,Today)))
```